# SignalR connection using subdomains

Tags: internet-explorer-7, forms-authentication, subdomain, signalr

I have successfully implemented SignalR into my project using hubs. Everything works fine in every browser. The only problem i have is with IE7. By design IE7 only allows 2 simultaneous requests to the same domain.
The solution for this problem is using a subdomain for opening the connection to SignalR.
In your first browser tab you can use for example channel1.domain.com and in your second one channel2.domain.com, and so on.

```
$.connection.hubs.url = "channel1.domain.com"
```

Now the problem is that in a request to the subdomain the cookies don't get send and obviously i'am not authenticated. (I'am using Forms Authentication).

Do i have to change the way I authenticate my users. Or maybe somebody can give me an alternative solution.

Comment: had you resolve this issue? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your cookie mask includes a subdomain (eg set your 'cookie domain' to ".domain.com" instead of the default, just "domain.com").

That way subdomains will inherit the parent domain cookies.

Comment: I tried that too. But SignalR makes a XHR request to one of my subdomains. In that request the cookies don't get send. Cookies don't get passed with XHR requests to subdomains I think...